# Smooth camera rotate around the player in 3rd person

Tags: rotation, smoothing, unity-game-engine

I have problem with smooth rotation, I'm trying to make a game with system of rotating like in Temple Run. I have no idea how to attach the smooth rotation by lerp for example to offset.

```
//Position
 public GameObject player;
 private Vector3 offSet;

 //Rotation
 //Quaternion localRotation;
 Quaternion leftRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3 (0, 90, 0));
 Quaternion rightRotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3 (0, -90, 0));

 Vector3 lRotation = new Vector3(0.0f, -90f, 0.0f);
 Vector3 rRotation = new Vector3(0.0f, 90f, 0.0f);

 void Start () {
     offSet = transform.position - player.transform.position;
 }

 void Update () {
 }

 void LateUpdate(){

     transform.position = player.transform.position + offSet;
     transform.LookAt (player.transform);

     if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.LeftArrow) && GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().turn) {

         offSet = Quaternion.Euler(lRotation)*offSet;
         transform.position = player.transform.position + offSet;
         transform.LookAt (player.transform);

     } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.RightArrow) && GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().turn) {

         offSet = Quaternion.Euler(rRotation)*offSet;
         transform.position = player.transform.position + offSet;
         transform.LookAt (player.transform);
     }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest performing [Transform.RotateAround()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html) on the camera's transform, using the player's game-object for the axis.

Example:

```
//in camera-code
transform.RotateAround(player.transform.position, Vector3.up, 45f);
```

I hope that helps!

**EDIT:**
In addition, you can also use [Mathf.LerpAngle](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.LerpAngle.html) instead of a fixed value as the third parameter, to ensure smoother results.

Comment: Thank you, Im not sure if thats gonna work, i need to make it stay in that rotation, because when i called RotateAround when i press key, it just rotate in rotation i set immediately and goes back to default rotation, so how can I make it stay in that rotation?

Comment: Ok I use that Mathf.LerpAngle function for that and it's working very good, only problem now is to stop rotation from looping after pressing key.

Comment: @MrAbeckon I'm not sure I understand. Could you please clarify?

Comment: My camera is now rotating how i want, when i press the key, but it's constantly rotating, instead of that i want to stop rotation after camera rotate for -90°/+90°.
This is my code now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35541760/how-to-stop-rotation-by-lerpangle-after-90

Comment: Your code still doesn't use `Transform.RotateAround`, which I still think would make it easier for you (and everyone else that uses the same code) to understand. Anyhow, looking at your code, I would suggest using `Debug.Log` to find the value of `lAngle` while the game is running and see if it matches with what you expect. I think it fails the `if (lAngle > 90f)` condition. All the best!